# Release build in MVS 2010 professional v/s express for C

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, performance, release

recently I discovered that "executing" a C program as a release build instead of a debug build optimizes the code and makes it run much faster. This is accessed through project properties > configuration manager menu. I would like to know if this feature is the same in the professional version and in the express edition of MVS 2010 in terms of speed optimization. I have the express edition.

Also, I would like to know if C programs run with the same speed as in both the professional and express editions. I understand that the professional edition has many "software" tools for the serious programmer.

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the compilers are exactly the same, so in the terms of the performance, you will get exactly same results. Difference is only in the tools and support, as you pointed out.

Comment: Thanks. With a particular code I'm getting around 30% reduction in time when I run the code as a release build.

Answer (score 3):

From the Visual Studio Express FAQ's (http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/support-faq.aspx):

> **Does Visual C++ 2008 Express include the "optimizing compiler"?**
>
> Yes, Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition includes the same core optimizing compiler that will be included with all other Visual Studio 2008 editions. Some new expanded optimization features, including Profile Guided Optimizations, will be available only in the Standard and above editions of Visual Studio 2008.

Therefore any optimisations that are available from the "Profile Guided Optimisations" will not be available in the Express edition.

This is quite a specific piece of functionality and you have to do some work to use it (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k32f4k.aspx) -

I don't think I've ever used it whilst writing C++ so it would be **reasonable to conclude that the Express version is practically the same as the Standard and Professional** versions

Comment: Thanks. I'm using C. The Profile Guided Optimisations seem too advanced for me :).

Comment: Then I believe that you should have identical results using the Express version as the Professional version. Release mode is always faster as it does additional optimisations.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the other answer as the information that you provided was for version 2008 and also as to give a boost to the other answerer's "low" reputation. All that you said might still hold well for version 2010 also. That said, you brought additional information as which specific piece of functionality might be an exception.